# java regular expression to replace all text up to a specific word

Tags: java, regex, string

I have some string that I am trying to parse and split the string into several pieces but the first piece has several additional text that I am trying to replace. I am not sure what the correct syntax in java is to do this:

```
    match = match.replace("*[^<Matches>]^", "");
    match = match.trim();
```

Match string contains the following:

```
<Response>
<RequestsUsed>81</RequestsUsed>
....
....
<Matches>
....
....
```

I want to replace all the text from  up to and including  but keep everything after.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: 1. `replace` doesn't support regex. 2. Avoid parsing XML using regex

Comment: use replaceAll or Pattern Matcher

Comment: You have misunderstood what `[]` is for in regexes.  The pattern `[^<Matches>]` will match *one* character that is not one of these: `<`, `M`, `a`, `t`, `c`, `h`, `e`, `s`, `>`.

Comment: If what you're parsing is on multiple lines, check one line at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and yes I did misunderstand the use of [].

Comment: oh why the negative vote though? I did research this and tried the suggested answers but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Matcher to do this as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
if(matcher.find())
{
    trimmedString = yourString.substring(matcher.start())
};
```

Comment: thanks. could you please suggest what the correct pattern would be? or a link to somewhere that explains this.